# Finding and removing a name in an ArrayList

Tags: java

Basically i am trying to search for specif names in an Array-list and then remove just that name.I am doing an assignment for college, and it species to search and remove by name, so i cant use the int index of, I am fairly new to java, so ill post my code maybe I am missing something any help would be great.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GaaClub {
    private ArrayList<Member> players;


    {
    }

    public GaaClub() {
        players = new ArrayList<Member>();

    }

    public void addStanderedMember() {
        // create a message object:
        StdOut.println("Please enter the members's name: ");
        StdIn.readLine();
        String name = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the members address: ");
        String address = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the members DOB: ");
        String dob = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the amount to Pay: ");
        double mempaid = StdIn.readDouble();
        Member player = new Member(name, address, dob, mempaid);
        players.add(player);
    }

    public void addStandaredPlayer() {
        // create a message object:
        StdOut.println("Please enter the standard Player's name: ");
        StdIn.readLine();
        String name = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the standard Player's address: ");
        String address = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the standard Player's DOB: ");
        String dob = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the amount to Pay: ");
        double mempaid = StdIn.readDouble();
        StandardPlayer player = new StandardPlayer(name, address, dob, mempaid);
        players.add(player);
    }

    public void addElitePlayer() {
        // create a message object:
        StdOut.println("Please enter the Elite Players's name: ");
        StdIn.readLine();
        String name = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the Elite Players's address: ");
        String address = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the Elite Players's DOB: ");
        String dob = StdIn.readLine();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the the amount to Pay: ");
        double mempaid = StdIn.readDouble();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the Elite Players's BMI: ");
        double bmi = StdIn.readDouble();
        StdOut.println("Please enter the Elite Players's height: ");
        double height = StdIn.readDouble();
        ElitePlayer player = new ElitePlayer(name, address, dob, mempaid, bmi,
                height);
        players.add(player);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GaaClub app = new GaaClub();
        app.run();
    }

    public void memberType() {
        StdOut.println("Enter Type of membership: ");
        StdOut.println("1) Add a Standard Member");
        StdOut.println("2) Add an Elite Player");
        StdOut.println("3) Add a Standard Player");
        String memberchoice = StdIn.readString();
        if (memberchoice.equals("1"))
            addStanderedMember();
        if (memberchoice.equals("2"))
            addElitePlayer();
        if (memberchoice.equals("3"))
            addStandaredPlayer();

    }

    public void listNames() {
        for (Member player : players) {
                player.list();  
        }
    }


    public  void removeName() {
        for (Member player : players) {
            listNames();
            String sResponse = StdIn.readString();
            if (sResponse.equals(player.name)) 
            {
                players.remove(player);;
                return;
            }
        }
}



    private int mainMenu() {
        StdOut.println("1) Add a Member");
        StdOut.println("2) Remove Player");
        StdOut.println("3) List Names");
        StdOut.println("4) List Members");
        StdOut.println("0) Exit");
        StdOut.print("==>>");
        int option = StdIn.readInt();
        return option;
    }

    public void run() {
        {
            StdOut.println("Posts");
            int option = mainMenu();
            while (option != 0) {
                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        memberType();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        removeName();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        addStanderedMember();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        listNames();
                        break;
                }
                option = mainMenu();
            }
            StdOut.println("Exiting..."); 
        }
    }
}
```

And Second file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Member {

    protected String name; 
    protected String address;
    protected String dob;
    protected double mempaid;

    public Member(String name, String address, String dob, double mempaid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.mempaid = mempaid ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void list(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public double getMempaid() {
        return mempaid;
    }

    public void setMempaid(double mempaid) {
        this.mempaid = mempaid;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", dob=" + dob
            + ", mempaid=" + mempaid + "]";
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StandardPlayer extends Member {
    private ArrayList<Competition> competition;

    public StandardPlayer(String name, String address, String dob,
            double mempaid) {
        super(name, address, dob, mempaid);

    }

    public ArrayList<Competition> getCopmetition() {
        return competition;
    }

    public void setCopmetition(ArrayList<Competition> copmetition) {
        this.competition = copmetition;
    }

    void addCompetiton(Competition c) {

    }

    void payMembership(double amt) {
        mempaid = 0;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StandardPlayer [competition=" + competition + ", name=" + name
            + ", address=" + address + ", dob=" + dob + ", mempaid="
            + mempaid + "]";
    }




}
```

And third file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ElitePlayer extends Member {
    private double bmi;
    private double height;
    private ArrayList<Competition> competition;

    public ElitePlayer(String name, String address,
                String dob, double mempaid, double bmi, double height) {
         super(name, address, dob, mempaid);
        this.bmi = bmi;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getBmi() {
        return bmi;
    }

    public void setBmi(double bmi) {
        this.bmi = bmi;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public ArrayList<Competition> getCopmetition() {
        return competition;
    }

    void payMembership(double amt) {
        mempaid = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ElitePlayer [bmi=" + bmi  + ", height=" + height
            + ", competition=" + competition + ", name=" + name
            + ", address=" + address + ", dob=" + dob + ", mempaid="
            + mempaid + "]";
    }

    public void setCompetition(ArrayList<Competition> competition) {
        this.competition = competition;`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't have time to read through it, but it should be as simple as a for loop, like (for int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) that looks for the string, like String searchString = "Bob", in the for loop, have if(list.get(i).equals(searchString)) return true; or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you already have a loop set-up for it. Just loop through the members, check if the name equals what you're looking for, then remove that member from the list if it is

```
for(Member mem : players) { //loop through each member in list
    if(mem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) { //check if member's name is "name"
        players.remove(mem); //removes member from list if it is
    }
}
```

`equalsIgnoreCase(String)` checks the string without checking for case sensitivity. It won't care for capitalization. If you care about capitalization, use `equals(String)`

Comment: Try to use That but i get this error  Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at GaaClub.removeName(GaaClub.java:93)
 at GaaClub.run(GaaClub.java:131)
 at GaaClub.main(GaaClub.java:67)

Comment: Well I couldn't run the code you gave us because it's missing a lot of things such as `StdOut`, `StdIn`, `Competition` type, and probably other things. I can't even compile this because you didn't give us enough code. It would also be nice if you cleaned up the code before posting it, a quick `cntrl+shift+f` and taking out a few un-used things would help out a lot. I found that switching to a regular loop `for(int i = 0; i < players.length; players++)` instead of using enhanced has fixed concurrentmod, but I can't navigate through your code. I answer based off 'find name in list and remove'

Comment: StdOut, StdIn are library's and you cant post  code here unless you align it with cntrl+k and it is still a work in progress things will be removed later, any way i sorted it out with this,   for(int i=players.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
   Member mem = players.get(i);
      if(mem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) { 
          players.remove(mem); 
      }
          }

Comment: That's weird. My JDK doesn't mention anything about it, and I'm using SE 7. That works as well, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` has a method which can remove by `Object`:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Bob");
arr.remove("Bob");
```

it removes the first instance of the object.

You could of course simulate the same debavior:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Bob");

String searchTerm = "Bob";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if (arr.get(i).equals(searchTerm) {
        arr.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

This deviation from the built in method would only be recommended if you wanted to have the search delete on some other, or similar condition. For example if it contained the word "Bob"...

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Bob Bobingston");

String searchTerm = "Bob";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if (arr.get(i).contains(searchTerm)) {
        arr.remove(i);
        break;
    } 
}
```